# Is there a compiler directive for Windows Phone emulator vs real hardware?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For example, we have:

```
#if DEBUG

#endif
```

is there such a compiler directive for the Emulator vs Real device hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to determine at runtime whether your code is running in the emulator or on a device, you can use `Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType`

If you really want to make seperate builds using compiler directives, then you can make any compiler directive you want for that purpose and integrate that to your build process. Say, #DEVICEBUILD.